# gettar attribute error - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr

I keep getting the following error when trying to use "getattr":

*AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'displayTime'*

Here is the code I am using:

```
    getattr(className,"displayTime")(self)
```

where "className" refers to a string that I have taken from a list and is also the name of a subclass I have in my program. "displayTime" is a method within that subclass.

I tried to test it by inputing the name of the subclass directly into it:

```
    getattr(seconds,"displayTime")(self)
```

and this worked fine. Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: you'd need to grab the class object via `globals()[classname]`; `getattr` won't find it for you. Consider creating a dictionary that holds classname->classobj values so you don't need to worry about going through `globals`.

Comment: you have to use the instance as the first argument, not a string.

Comment: `seconds` is not `"seconds"`. A string represents text, not a class or anything else whose name happens to match the text stored in the string.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing the `getattr` correctly. Your problem is that you need to convert from a string to an object - in this case, a reference to a *class* object.

There are two ways to identify classes. First, you can identify them using their parent module, something like `abc.ABCMeta`. To do this, start with the `sys.modules` dictionary, and look up modules and submodules (that is: look up 'abc'). Then you will have a module, which will have the last part of the name ('ABCMeta') as one of its children. You can use `getattr` to extract the child from the module, and then use `getattr` again to get whatever member you want.

```
import sys
mod = sys.modules['abc']
cls = getattr(mod, 'ABCMeta')
method = getattr(cls, 'displayTime') # Won't work, not available on class
```

The second approach is to assume that you have a name in your global namespace in whatever module you are using. For example, if you did something like:

```
from abc import ABCMeta as chicken
```

You could then refer to a global symbol, `chicken`, in your code, and it would mean the same thing. In this case, if you *have* already done the import, you can simply look up `'chicken'` in the `globals()` dictionary, as @Jim Fasarakis Hilliard suggested in a comment:

```
clsname = 'chicken'
cls = globals()[clsname]
method = getattr(cls, 'displayTime')
```